# How to perform k-means on data larger than RAM?

Tags: c++, large-data

I have implemented the k-means algorithm to cluster data. The data I'm working with can be larger than the amount of RAM I have available. Is there a common way (in C++) to handle these kind of problems?

Comment: Amount of RAM, or amount of address space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are incremental k-means algorithms out there : http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/papers/fastkmeans.pdf

C++ source code : https://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This way it's possible to perform k-means on a much larger data set.